# Only last statement being executed within if statement

Tags: c#, combobox, vsto, excel-2010

I have an excel 2010 add-in I'm working on in Visual Studio 2010, and I need to fill three comboBox's with the same information. So I have a for loop running through, then I'm filling them all right after each other but only the last one is being filled.

```
public void tableScheme()
    {


        comboBox4.Items.Clear();
        comboBox5.Items.Clear();
        comboBox6.Items.Clear();

        for (int j = 1; j <= schemaTable.Rows.Count; j++)
        {


            //string tableColumns = ("["+Convert.ToString(schemaTable.Rows[j - 1][0])+"]");
            RibbonDropDownItem item = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
            item.Label = "testTEST";




            if (j == schemaTable.Rows.Count)
            {
                    comboBox4.Items.Add(item);
                    comboBox5.Items.Add(item);
                    comboBox6.Items.Add(item);



            }
            else
            {
                    comboBox4.Items.Add(item);
                    comboBox5.Items.Add(item);
                    comboBox6.Items.Add(item);


            }

        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why it's only populating the last comboBox. I know that this is what's happening because I switched the comboBox6 with comboBox4 and then it only populated comboBox4. Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: I THINK thats because your item variable can only be in 1 combobox or something like that.

Comment: So maybe if I make a different variable/item object for each comboBox?

Comment: I don't know for sure but you can try. I don't know what this does: RibbonDropDownItem but I think this makes it so that the item can only be assigned to 1 box try using break points or something like that to assign item to another combo box every few seconds so you can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments might have suggested, you have an object reference problem.

Rewrite your add code thusly:

```
comboBox4.Items.Add(new RibbonDropDownItem() { Label = "the text" });
...
```

Then repeat that idea for every item you want to add, which will give you a fresh instance of `RibbonDropDownItem` for each addition to every combo box.